# How to get the folder name in which Jenkins pipeline job is running

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am writing a JenkinsFile for pipeline to pass few variables from the pipeline to a downstream freestyle job. I need the value of the folder name in which my pipeline is.

I have checked the Ownership plugin(https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Ownership+Plugin). This provides information only about job and node ownership.

I've done following for job ownership details

```
println "Primary owner ID: ${ownership.job.primaryOwnerId}"
println "Primary owner e-mail: ${ownership.job.primaryOwnerEmail}"
```

I want something similar for **folder ownership** in JenkinsFile that I am writing. I also tried finding some environment variables that can give this value but couldn't find any.

Any help via some plugin methods(as used for job owner) or some environment variable will be appreciated.

Comment: You looking for folder name in Jenkins structure or workspace name of current build of pipeline in Jenkins node?

Comment: @sintasy Folder name in Jenkins structure; For a pipeline when you click it in the job's list , It first opens a list of branches and pull requests. I want the owners mentioned there, which is shown as 'Folder Owners'

Answer (score 0):

For the absolute path of your workspace you should use the WORKSPACE variable. It will bring the path in this format:

*jenkins home*/workspace/*job name*